# Confidence interval of a linear function of a multinomial distribution

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution, dice

Say we have a $K$ sided (unfair) dice, that has unknown probabilities $p_k$ of rolling each side.  We roll $N$ trials and observe $n_k$ occurrences of each side (so $N = \sum_{k=1}^K {n_k}$).   The average roll $\hat a$ of our trial is $\hat a = \sum_{k=1}^K k n_k/N$.

I would like to find a confidence interval on $a=\sum_{i=1}^K k p_k$. In some cases $N$ is fairly small, so I don't think we can make a normal approximation (we will have $n_k \hat{p}_k < 5$).

I'm currently doing this with a bootstrap simulation.  I estimate the Laplace smoothed $\hat{p}_k = \frac{n_k + 1}{N+K}$, and then bootstrap $N$ samples a bunch of times, and look at the empirical confidence interval.

What's a good way to go about this analytically?

It seems like we could get a confidence interval on $p_k$ using one of these techniques (other than the normal approximation) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

but I'm not sure how you go about combining them to get a bound on $a$.

Comment: You might want to revisit the normal approximation: it can be surprisingly good, even for small dice with $N=2$.  The $n_k\hat p_k \lt 5$ criterion doesn't apply to this situation--that's for testing distributional hypotheses with a $\chi^2$ statistic, not for estimating a mean.

Comment: @whuber so how would I combine the individual CI on $p_k$ in that case?

Comment: You don't need them: construct a CI on the mean in the usual way, as the sample mean plus or minus a multiple of the sample standard deviation.